# Can anybody explain why these two ActionResults return different results despite being the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I'm making a portfolio. In my Portfolio view, I have the following code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Project", new { _title = @ViewBag.ProjectContainer.Projects[x].Title, _imagePath = @ViewBag.ProjectContainer.Projects[x].ImagePath, _brief = @ViewBag.ProjectContainer.Projects[x].Brief, _description = @ViewBag.ProjectContainer.Projects[x].FullDescription, })" class=" readmore-button button">Learn More</a>
```

It's placed within a loop that goes through the ViewBag and draws a button for each "Project" in the "Project Container". When clicked, this should lead to the project page and display the relevant information.

When written as above (calling the Index() method in the Project controller) everything works as intended and the page displays thusly:

http://gyazo.com/57901eab7ccf8be45270312a92880072

However, when I call another method in my controller, which I have named "SetProject", the following happens:

http://gyazo.com/6a5c6164dc4e8b55ec8a6684ce469652

My controller methods look like the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(string _title, string _imagePath, string _brief, string _description)
{
    ProjectViewModel proj = new ProjectViewModel { Title = _title, ImagePath = _imagePath, Brief = _brief, FullDescription = _description };
    return View("Project", proj);
}

public ActionResult SetProject(string _title, string _imagePath, string _brief, string _description)
{
    ProjectViewModel proj = new ProjectViewModel { Title = _title, ImagePath = _imagePath, Brief = _brief, FullDescription = _description };
    return View("Project", proj);
}
```

You might noticed that these are identical - hence my question, WHY do they look so different? Why does the second simply not work?

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and the Razor view engine and trying to learn, but got very stuck here. Would appreciate any and all help.

Could this be something to do with the Route config? The only difference I can see is the URL being different for the broken one (having the extra "/SetProject")

Comment: It looks like the second one doesn't use stylesheets. What is the path, what does your browser's console say about failed requests?

Comment: The console seems bare, other than saying "Navigation Accepted".

The URL for the "SetProject" method is "http://localhost:10062/Project/SetProject?" followed by the long list of parameters.

The URL for the "Index" method is "http://localhost:10062/Project?" followed by the same

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the second simply not work?

Because of your css references.It is working actualy just it doesn't look like what you expected. Make sure you include your all css references inside of `Layout` and make sure your  Project View using your `Layout` page.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? Both of the controller methods return the same view with the same viewmodel but the index one draws perfectly fine. All of my views seems to be using my default _Layout as set in the _ViewStart class

Comment: @user3261018 I can't say anything about your Views because you didn't provide your View's code.If you are sure your page using your layout then try to add css references inside of your Project view manually and see what happens

Comment: There's only one view, the "Project" view, and they both return it. The only difference is it only renders correctly for some reason with the Index() method.

I took your advice and made sure it was using the correct layout, I added
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

To the top of the view, but it yielded no success.

Comment: Actually, the .css file is the same for both. When you look at the source of both pages, they only differ in what appear to be GUID's identifying several images. The only difference I cannot fathom is the line  `<meta property="og:url" content="http://gyazo.com/57901eab7ccf8be45270312a92880072"/>` for the first link versus `<meta property="og:url" content="http://gyazo.com/6a5c6164dc4e8b55ec8a6684ce469652"/>` for the second. I fail to see though how a meta property could affect the rendering in such a fundamental way.

Comment: It's worth noting those gyazo links are just images I uploaded, not the actual website I am working on